# Looping through a table rows with comparisons using VUgen

Tags: javascript, syntax, loadrunner, vugen

I have a table I need to compare each of the values within to an existing parameter.

I have this Xpath here: //*[@id="maincontent"]/messages/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/span

and would like to insert an increment variable from the loop to go through the /tr/ in the table only.

Here is what i have so far:

```
var i;
var max = 10;

var xpathleft = `*[@id="maincontent"]/messages/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[`;
var xpathright = `]/td[4]/div/span`;                                                                                

for (i = 1; i < max, i++)
    {
    var currentXpath = string.concat(xpathleft, i, xpathright);
}

if (currentXpath.innerHTML == PartnerIDs)
    {
    lr_log_message("Match Found!");
}
```

This is currently sitting in an Evaluate Javascript step in TruClient/VUgen and is giving me Syntax Error: Unexpected Token )

The element here doesn't have any ID I can reference and looks like this: Partner ID

and has been difficult to pull the needed Partner ID text within code.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < max, i++)` should be `for (i = 1; i < max; i++)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your JavaScript syntax is incorrect.
Try this:

```
var i;
var max = 10;

var xpathleft = `*[@id="maincontent"]/messages/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[`;
var xpathright = `]/td[4]/div/span`;                                                                                

for (i = 1; i < max; i++){
    var currentXpath = `${xpathleft}${i}${xpathright}`;


   if (currentXpath.innerHTML == PartnerIDs) {
       lr_log_message("Match Found!");
   }
}
```